# delete record form intermediate table in many to many relations in django

Tags: django-views

I have two models such as clinic and doctor. I have a list of clinics which are associated with a specific doctor by this CBV

```
class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Doctor
# slug = none
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['clinic_hospital_list'] = self.object.clinic_hospital.all()
    return context
```

I want other CBV which delete clinic that has association with doctor.

Comment: So I assume you do not want to delete the clinic, but only the *relation* between a clinic and doctor?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a [**`DeleteView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) that works on the "through model" between the doctor and the hospital:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DoctorClinicDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Doctor.clinic_hospital.through
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some_view')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        return get_object_or_404(
            queryset,
            doctor_id=self.kwargs['doctor_id'],
            clinic_id=self.kwargs['clinic_id']
        )
```

and in the `urls.py`, you then make a path with:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:doctor_id>/<int:clinic_id>/delete', DoctorClinicDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_doctor_clinic'),
    # …
]
```

Then you make a POST or DELETE request to the view for a given `doctor_id` and `clinic_id` to remove that relation.

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed: well likely that means you mix args and kwargs in a call to reverse. But since we here never call a reverse anyway, the error is located somewhere else.